# In Isaiah 60:5 what turns to Israel from the sea?

Tags: isaiah, prophecy

Is Isaiah 60:5 saying that:

- "All of the fish of the sea swim to your shore"?
- "All the treasures of the sea are extracted for you on your shore"?
- "Ships come from across the sea bearing goods"?

And also,

- The gentile armies arrive at your borders
- The gentiles arrive at your borders bearing gifts
- Gentile weapons come to you

> YLT Isaiah 60:5 Then thou seest, and hast become bright, And thine heart hath been afraid and enlarged, For turn unto thee doth the multitude of the sea, The forces of nations do come to thee.

Here are some ways it has been rendered:

https://biblehub.com/isaiah/60-5.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some clues are to be found in Isaiah chapter 59 which speaks of the Redemer who "will come to Zion to those in Jacob who repent of their sins" (NIV).  Although this prophecy points to the coming of the Messiah, it had an initial fulfilment at the end of the Babylonian exile and the return of God's people to their land and the rebuilding of the Temple.

A very simple explanation becomes apparent, as explained in the NIV Study Bible comments with regard to Isaiah 60:5:

> Jerusalem will be enriched by the nations (see verse 11; 61:6; 66:12). The contribution of King Darius to Zerubbabel's temple may be a partial fulfilment (Ezra 6:8-9)

Isaiah chapter 60 verse 5 is a description of how the restored nation will be blessed by the riches of the sea and the wealth of the nations.  A time of prosperity comes to Israel.

Yes, some people interpret this to the future Messianic kingdom, and others interpret this to the influx of Gentiles into the church, but the initial application is simply a description of how the nation of Israel would be blessed materially, to the glory of God.

As to the future, God will likewise bless all who repent of their sins - Jew and Gentile alike.

Answer (score 1):

This is part of a long Messianic prophecy (all texts from The NWT):-

> Isaiah 59:20  “To Zion the Repurchaser will come,. . ."
>
> Isaiah 60:5  "At that time you will see and become radiant, And your heart will throb and overflow, Because the wealth of the sea will be directed to you; The resources of the nations will come to you."

As vs. 5 is in the midst of a Messianic prophecy it is referring to people coming to Jesus from the nations of the earth and using all their power, goods, lives etc. is service to God as Christians.

> Isaiah 61:1  "The spirit of the Sovereign Lord Jehovah is upon me [Jesus], Because Jehovah **anointed [Messiah] me to declare good news** to the meek. He sent me to bind up the brokenhearted, To proclaim liberty to the captives And the wide opening of the eyes to the prisoners,

X-ref to the above:-

> Luke 4:17-21    "So the scroll of the prophet Isaiah was handed to him [Jesus], and he opened the scroll and found the place where it was written: 18 “Jehovah’s spirit is upon me, because he anointed me to declare good news to the poor. He sent me to proclaim liberty to the captives and a recovery of sight to the blind, to send the crushed ones away free, 19 to preach Jehovah’s acceptable year.” 20 With that he rolled up the scroll, handed it back to the attendant, and sat down; and the eyes of all in the synagogue were intently fixed on him. 21 Then he began to say to them: “Today this scripture that you just heard is fulfilled.”
>
> Isaiah 62:11  "Look! Jehovah has proclaimed to the ends of the earth: “Say to the daughter of Zion, ‘Look! Your salvation is coming. Look! His reward is with HIM, And the wage he pays is before him.’”
>
> Galations 3:14  "This was so that the ***blessing*** of Abraham would ***come to the nations by means of Christ Jesus,. . ."***

Below is From http://www.jesuswalk.com/isaiah/11_glory.htm:-

> Then you will look and be radiant, 
>   your heart will throb and swell with joy; 
>   the wealth on the seas will be brought to you, 
>   to you the riches of the nations will come." (60:4-5)
>
> "Jerusalem" is a kind of shorthand to refer to the people of God ... Thus some of this prophecy is being fulfilled by the spread of the Christian church throughout history.

Comment: Like "fishers of men"?

Comment: Somthing like that etc. etc..

Comment: In Isaiah 60:5 who "will see and become radiant"? Messiah?

Comment: Isa 60:5 reffering to the "woman" of vs 1 a  symbolic wife of God as in Isa 54:5 For thy Maker is THINE HUSBAND the LORD of hosts is his name; and thy Redeemer the Holy One of Israel The God of the whole earth shall he be called.6 For the LORD hath called thee as a woman forsaken and grieved in spirit and a wife of youth when thou wast refused, saith thy God. - of which God is the Head/Husband & Jesus is the eldest Son & that "nations" (humans) that join God's family as Christians who go to heaven cause geart Joy to God's heavenly organisation of vs.5 his symbolic Wife the "woman" of Isa. 60:1

Answer (score 1):

Isa 60 and 61 is part of a series of Messianic prophecies about the coming Messiah and His people and city, Jerusalem.  Some parts were clearly fulfilled as Jesus' first Advent.  For example, Jesus directly quoted from Isa 61:1-4 in Luke 4:16-19 in His first sermon as the key-note address and theme for all His ministry.

Some parts are clearly unfulfilled like the early parts of Isa 60.  It is possible that the Jerusalem that we know might have fulfilled this prophecy but its citizens rebelled at Jesus' ministry and invitations and they were rejected (Matt 23:37, 38, see also v33-36).  See Jer 18:7-10 and 17:24-26 vs Jer 17:27.

The safest way to interpret this passage is to notice the way it is used by the inspired NT writers, if any.  In this case Isa 61:5 is quoted by Rev 21:24 in John's prophecy of the New Jerusalem.  Thus we wait for the fulfilment of this prophecy in the New Jerusalem.  It is clearly a time of universal peace when the somewhat metaphoric language describes an international political situation that acknowledges the importance of the New Jerusalem.

This important Jerusalem (in prophecy) is signalled by the cargoes being brought to Jerusalem by everyone, including produce from the sea.  In other words, Jerusalem, or more correctly, the New Jerusalem is central and most important city and is the capital of the world and the seat of God's government and throne, according to Revelation.